# Can I monitor cost for one particular instance and resources associated with it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I monitor cost for one particular EC2 instance, and resources associated with it in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Detailed Billing.. This will save cost for each AWS resource in your S3 bucket in CSV format. You do not paying anything extra for this service except S3 storage charge for that file.  Download the CSV file and filter for the instance you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can Tag the EC2 instance with a Tag Key-Value pair using [EC2 Tagging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) feature so that you will be able see the cost in billing for the particular EC2 instance with the Tag.

Also you can use the same tag for EC2 and associated resources such as EBS Volumes, VPC & etc.

Answer (score 1):

First thing .. enable details billing. 
Then for your requirement you can create tags for each of your resource then start receiving cost allocation reports that break down the per instance cost for each of the tags you set up.

The below lines are from aws documentation for your reference:

You can use tags to organize your resources, and cost allocation tags to track your AWS costs on a detailed level. After you activate cost allocation tags, AWS uses the cost allocation tags to organize your resource costs on your cost allocation report, to make it easier for you to categorize and track your AWS costs. AWS provides two types of cost allocation tags, an AWS-generated tag and user-defined tags. AWS defines, creates, and applies the AWS-generated tag for you, and you define, create, and apply user-defined tags. You must activate both types of tags separately before they can appear in Cost Explorer or on a cost allocation report.

[AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html)

Hope it will help!

Comment: I think you already got your answer.. was busy editing my answer from mobile browser .. anyways enjoy you got your answer